# Convert BizTalk 2010 trial version to full version

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-deployment

I downloaded BizTalk server 2010 evaluation edition, I have enterprise edition serial number.

But when I am installing its taking evaluation version serial and its not giving option to enter my full version serial number.

Is there any way to change the default evaluation version serial number?

How to enable the serial number fields?

Below I am providing the BizTalk server setup screenshot.

[image]

Comment: The evaluation version is only meant to be used for evaluation purposes. You will need to re-install using your Enterprise edition if you want to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the Enterprise Edition installation over the top of the Evaluation one.